# firstLast Java Linked list/nodes

Tags: java, nodes

I'm confused on how each node gets linked to another and how to make sure that if I want the first node to be linked in after the one at the end, I'm not running an infinite loop. For example, in this problem..

Write a method firstLast that could be added to the LinkedIntList class that moves the first element of the list to the back end of the list. Suppose a LinkedIntList variable named list stores the following elements from front (left) to back (right):

[18, 4, 27, 9, 54, 5, 63]
If you made the call of list.firstLast();, the list would then store the elements in this order:

[4, 27, 9, 54, 5, 63, 18]
If the list is empty or has just one element, its contents should not be modified.

My first attempt is to do this..but to no avail:

```
`public void firstLast(){
    ListNode temp = front;//stores/references the first node
    temp.next = null;//ensures that first node isn't referring to any other 
//node
    ListNode current = front;//reaches end node/first one with a null 
//reference
    while(current.next != null){
        current = current.next;
    }
    front.next = temp;//links end node to first node
    front = current.next;////now that skips the first element`
```

but the output is `[18] -> [18] (cycles!)` . Please advise

Comment: doesn't your linkedlist implementation provide `pop` and `push`? this method you are implementing should rely on those

Comment: Draw an image, very helpful to visualize what is going on when dealing with data-structures, like here: http://i.imgur.com/7sSmB0x.jpg. The black arrows are the **next** pointers you are trying to manipulate. Now visualize what your algorithm does. For your specific task - simply point the **next** of the last element to it, make it **tail** and make the previous second element to **head**. **Important**: No need for iterating the whole thing, *THAT* is the advantage of the `LinkedList` concept to other data-structures!

Comment: GUIDO, no it doesn't have `pop` and `push`. Do linkedlists usually have that in Java? (I thought it was only stacks that do..

Comment: Zabuza, I was only iterating through it to find the end node. Is that not neccesary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm confused on how each node gets linked to another

In a single-linked list, every node knows only the next one.
So you need to keep track of the first,
commonly called `head` (in your implementation it's "front"),
because it's essential to access all the elements.

> ... and how to make sure that if I want the first node to be linked in after the one at the end, I'm not running an infinite loop.

The last node has no next node after it, so it's `next` pointer is `null`.
You can use this condition to avoid infinite loops.
(Just make sure the last node has `next` correctly as `null`.)

Your implementation could be fixed as:

```
public void firstLast() {
    // list is empty or has single element -> nothing to do
    if (front == null || front.next == null) {
        return;
    }

    // save the first
    ListNode first = front;

    // move the head
    front = front.next;

    // find the end
    ListNode current = front;
    while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }

    // append the node
    current.next = first;

    // reset the next pointer of the new last node
    first.next = null;
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot. So I'd run into an infinite loop when the last node's pointer isn't null? In that case, when my while loop changes `current` to `current.next` wouldn't I run out of nodes (and their pointers) so shouldn't the loop stop?

Comment: @Anna If the linked list has a cycle, you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: how do you tell if the linked list has a cycle?  (Sorry for all the questions, I'm self-learning this stuff)

Comment: @Anna when there are no `next` fields that point to `null` in a linked list. Think of it as a chain linked together in a loop. If you start at the beginning of the chain, there's no definitive end of the chain as you traverse down the links.

Comment: @cody.codes that makes sense... your condition for the travsersing down the loop would never be false (equate to null). Thanks!

Comment: @Anna yes, so you would need a condition to stop traversing to avoid infinite loop. For that you could store a pointer to the `start` node (any other node would be fine too), and as you traverse with `node = node.next`, check that `node != start`, which would indicate that you're back to the start, which would mean the list is circular (and you need to stop traversing)

Answer (score 4):

The function firstLast() can be coded as follows:

```
public void firstLast()
{
    ListNode temp = removeFirst();
    appendLast( temp );
}
```

So, now you have broken the problem down into two smaller problems.  This tends to be a very good strategy to solving any kind of problem.

The point you need to remember, in order to implement your `removeFirst()` is that you have to modify `front` to point to the 2nd node, which is `front.next`.

Comment: So in `removeFirst()` before I modifed the `front` to point to the `front.next`, I'd store its link/object(not really sure which it really is) in a temporary node right?

Answer (score 1):

Given you implemented:

```
void push(ListItem item) {
    end.next = item;
    item.next = null;
}
```

and

```
ListItem pop() {
    ListItem first = front;
    front = front.next;
    return first;
}
```

your method becomes:

```
void firstLast() {
    push(pop());
}
```

**Note**: untested code with no checks for *null*s or list size.